# Linux screen lock sometimes fails after lid close/open

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, lock-screen, suspend

I have Ubuntu Lunar 23.04 on Lenovo Yoga 7 14''.

When I close the lid, the system goes into suspend, as expected. Then on open, screen lock pops up, with a password prompt.

However sometimes after opening the lid, I can still see desktop contents, then the screen lock shows after a second.

Is it possible that the screen lock is spawned on lid OPEN instead of CLOSE?

What is the exact sequence of programs spawning on lid close/open that eventually leads to screen lock prompt?

Comment: Lid close / open, suspend, and other lid actions require proper power management drivers and BIOS (UEFI) for your computer and operating system.  See if there is a better power management driver for your OS.